# Find a specific string in a cdata string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, jsctypes

I've been reading up a bit on [using data types in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Working_with_data), specifically CData. I have a specific use case with a numeric string I'm running a regex pattern on. It's already fairly performant for what I'm doing, but I'm interested in possibly making it more performant for larger applications.

I am representing multi-dimensional models as a single string of integers (doesn't *have* to be integers, but that's worked for me so far). I represent empty space with `0`, occupied space as `1`, and each successive dimensional divide with an integer, beggining with `2` for 2-dimensions.

3 1D:

```
000
```

3x3 2D:

```
00020002000
```

3x3x3 3D:

```
00020002000300020002000300020002000
```

There's a bunch of stuff involved with making the regex pattern, but essentially it looks like this for 2D (this is a super-dumbed-down version for ease):

```
var gridWidth = //total width of our grid
var columns = //width of our object to place in grid
var rows = //height of our object to place in grid
var grid = 00020002000;

// (0{number of columns})+(([0-2]{difference in width of grid and object})(0{number of columns again)).repeat(number of rows) 
var reg = RegExp(("(0{" + columns + "})" + ("([0-2]{" + (gridWidth + 1 - columns) + "})(0{"+columns+"})").repeat(rows-1)) + "");

grid = grid.replace(reg, function(){
    //the last 2 argument's aren't part of our grouping
    var l = arguments.length - 2;
    r = "";
    for (var i = 1; i<l; ++i){
        if (i%2){
            r+= "1".repeat(columns); //repeat prototyped, just repeats string x times
        } else {
            r+= arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return r;
});
```

CData integers seem to be somehow more performant than javascript strings from what I'm reading, though I'm not experienced with C or the finer points of higher-level programming. I'm a javascript code monkey - feel free to tell me I'm WAY off base with my train of thought.

So my question is, is it possible to take my grid (which is essentially an integer), turn it into/store it as CData, and run my regex pattern against it somehow in an effort to increase performance processing large numbers of object in a very large grid space?

(side note: I have been able to place 10000 objects of random sizes between 1x1 and 4x4 in a grid using `div`s in an average of about 14000ms in chrome, so it's performant for basic grid layouts [registers as 0ms sometimes with only a few dozen objects on a small grid.] Handling placing objects more efficiently may inspire greater uses)

Answer (score 0):

"More performant" is all relative to what you're trying to accomplish.

The CData spec you were reading from is a draft.  In the meantime, keep it simple - try arrays.  The regex seems like a novel idea, but also seems to me that it would be quite difficult to maintain.

Comment: I've been hearing this quite a bit, but it does seem rather drab to use an array data structure and loop through it, unless there's a better way to search multiple places in an array that I don't know of. My method has allowed me to search once and find space for an object, or pass an index to detect collision, etc. I know internally there's probably arrays involved in searching the string with regex, but it seems more performant than js arrays already. I'll be testing more thoroughly once I have it refined a bit. Also looking at bitwise operators.